# LNK2019 When trying to inherit a class

Tags: c++, inheritance, linker-errors, lnk2019

So, I'm trying to inherit a class from another.
I have the base class Entity and I have a Hero class that needs to be inherited from it.

Like usual, I do this like this:

```
#include "Entity.h"

class Hero : public Entity
{
public:
    Hero(Sprite* sprite_, Scene* scene, float xPosition, float yPosition, const char* name);
    ~Hero(void);
};
```

My entity class:

```
#include "Sprite.h"
#include <vector>
#include "Scene.h"

class Entity
{
public:
    Entity(void);
    Entity(Sprite* Sprite_);
    Entity(Sprite* Sprite_, Scene* scene, float xPosition, float yPosition, const char*);
    ~Entity(void);
}
```

And the erorr I get is:

```
1>Hero.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Entity::Entity(void)" (??0Entity@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Hero::Hero(class Sprite *,class Scene *,float,float,char const *)" (??0Hero@@QAE@PAVSprite@@PAVScene@@MMPBD@Z)
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an implementation for `Entity::Entity(void);`

Comment: Not so. Read the message again. He's missing `Entity::Entity(void)`, which is *used by* `Hero::Hero(Sprite *, Scene *, float, float, char const *)`.

Comment: Oh, I feel so stupid, I really couldn't figure out where it was coming from... Will accept your answer when possible!

Answer (score 2):

From the error message, you've declared by not defined your `Entity::Entity(void);` You've probably forgotten to include the file with its implementation when you compiled/linked.

Edit: One minor aside on style: in C++, you usually want to use something like: `Entity()` rather than `Entity(void)`. In C, the `void` is necessary to make that a function prototype that tells the compiler that about the (lack of) parameters, rather than a function declaration that only tells the compiler the return type. C++, however, doesn't have anything equivalent to a C function declaration; a C++ function declaration *always* includes information about the parameter types, so an empty parentheses tells the compiler that the function takes no parameters.

Comment: I didn't forget to include anything, that was the weird thing.. But thanks for the heads up about the void thing

Answer (score 0):

That error means that it couldn't link the declaration to an actual function implementation.

Which usually means you didn't implement it, or you implemented something you thought was it, but actually with a slightly different signature.